# How fill a Point[] array from a String[] array?

Tags: java, c#, android, arrays, sockets

I have these coordinates with a separator **`:`**

```
I/System.out: {X=282,Y=990}:
I/System.out: {X=290,Y=990}:
I/System.out: {X=298,Y=990}:
I/System.out: {X=310,Y=990}:
I/System.out: {X=314,Y=990}:
```

and want fill a `Point[]` array with they, then i trying:

```
private String[] tokens = coordinates.split(Pattern.quote(":"));
private Point[] moviments = new Point[8192];

for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
     moviments[i] = new Point(tokens[i]);
```

but have a error of "incompatible types". How solve it?

---

**EDITION:**

The coordinates above are sent from this code over `Socket`:

**C#** (sender)

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

private List<Point> lstPoints;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lstPoints = new List<Point>();
        lstPoints.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lstPoints.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lstPoints.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Point obj in lstPoints)
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(obj) + ":" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    serverSocket.Send("MDRAWEVENT" + sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

**android** (receiver)

```
import java.net.Socket;

String xline;

while (clientSocket.isConnected()) {

    BufferedReader xreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    if (xreader.ready()) {

        while ((xline = xreader.readLine()) != null) {
                xline = xline.trim();

            if (xline != null && !xline.trim().isEmpty()) {

                if (xline.contains("MDRAWEVENT")) {

                    String coordinates = xline.replace("MDRAWEVENT", "");
                    String[] tokens = coordinates.split(Pattern.quote(":"));

                    /*
                      Point[] moviments = new Point[8192];

                       for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                            moviments[i] = new Point(tokens[i]);
                    */

                    mouseDraw(moviments);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void mouseDraw(Point[] segments) {

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(segments[0].x, segments[0].y);

    for (int i = 1; i < segments.length; i++) {

        path.lineTo(segments[i].x, segments[i].y);

        // After draw line, set the next start point
        path.moveTo(segments[i].x, segments[i].y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of class `Point`. Most probably, there is no c'tor present that takes a single `String` as argument.

Comment: @Turing85, `Point` is native of android.

Comment: I'm assuming that Point is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.8

Point requires 2 ints to create and not a string,  you will need to parse the string into the required data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that these **I/System.out:**  are not part of the received String, otherwise you would need to modify the code below in order to skip/ignore them (using `String.replace` for example).

After calling this:

```
private String[] tokens = coordinates.split(Pattern.quote(":"));
```

You separate the text using the litteral **:**, therefore the token you will obtain in the tokens array are of the form:

**{X=282,Y=990}**

On the other hand [the Android Point class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point) has three constructors

- No args constructor: `Point()`
- Two args constructor (coordinates x and y of a point): `Point(int x, int y)`
- One arg constructor (Another Point as source): `Point(Point source)`

None of these constructor matches your data model so you need:

- To split each token to get each coordinate separately
- To convert them into integer
- Then call the two args constructor

**Another option** would be to use the no args constructor then call the `set(int x, int y)` method to set the coordinates. I prefer the first approach.

So change your loop in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   String[] coordinates = tokens[i].replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(",");

   int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0].split("=")[1]);
   int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1].split("=")[1]);

   moviments[i] = new Point(x, y);
}
```

This should work.